# angular7 button are missing if screen is full

Tags: html, angular

I am a angular 7 newbie and got a problem that I do not know how to fix.
A app has some html that I list below:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AndroidShop</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src='http://www.amjet.biz/android/shop/images/{{product.imageUrl}}'>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {{product.description}}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        NT$ {{product.price}}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="nextProduct()">Next product</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="prevProduct()">Previous product</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="addCart()">Add to Cart</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="viewCart()">View Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The app works but buttons in component.html are not displayed and no scroll bar on screen.
What should I do to fix this? If more information need, please let me know

Thanks,

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz

Comment: I'd first check if it's Angular-related at all. Does it appear with just the HTML and CSS from your template and style sheets?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap use `col-12` inside `row`.

Comment: Thanks Hareesh, I did not use bootstrap grid system correctly. After add div with class 'col', the buttons show up in the buttom of screen but only half of them. Seems container div does not have enough height. Will container div provide scrollbar automaticaly if height is beyond screen height or I have to fix it on my own? Thanks for all reponse.